# drop down list selected index changed event handler in User Control

Tags: drop-down-menu, user-controls, event-handling

I have a UserControl:'TestControl' - which has one DropDownList: 'TestDDL' and a TextBox: 'TestAdditionalNotes' (there are no buttons or anything else in the Control that will cause a post back - and I don't need a postback as most of the data is client side). I have written a event handler for onSelectedIndexChange event in the Control. This control will be used in a 'Repeater Control' - Now I have a Testpage: 'Test.aspx' I have registered this user control on the test page - now what I want : When I change the DropDown list selected item in the contorl - the textbox should be visible/in visible based on my selection. But how to trigger the evenhandler on the control from the test page ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem... my code and the handlers where correct... it was just on that particular test page some javascripts libraries missing - which are required by the telerik rad control i.e the dropdown list... once I added those files manually... everything works...
(I figured this out by trying  the control on a different page and the event was being raised).... Thanks